# Limit of a sequence defined by recursive relation : $ a_n = \sqrt{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

We're given a sequence defined by the recursive relation: $$a_n = \sqrt{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}}$$

$a_1$ and $a_2$ are positive constants.
We have to show the following:

1. The sequences $\{ b_n \} = \{ a_{2n-1} \}$ and $\{ c_n \} = \{ a_{2n} \} $ are monotonic, and if one is increasing, the other is decreasing.
2. The limit of the sequence $\{ a_n \} $ is $ \left(a_1a_2^2\right)^{\frac13} $

---

Now, I have proved the first part. Besides that, I have also proved a few other things:

If $a_1 > a_2$, then:

a. $ \{ b_n \} $ decreases, and $ \{ c_n \} $ increases.

b. $ c_n < b_n $

If $a_1 < a_2$, we just flip $\{ b_n \}$ and $\{c_n\}$

Besides, I have also shown that both the sequences : $\{b_n\}$ and $\{ c_n\}$ have the same limit. What I don't know, is how to evaluate the limit.

Comment: What is $a_{n+1}^2\cdot a_n$?

Comment: Wow. Okay, I think this will be enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the relation $a_{n} = \sqrt{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}}$ for $n \geqslant 2$, we find that

$$a_{n+1}^2a_n = (\sqrt{a_na_{n-1}})^2a_n = a_na_{n-1}a_n = a_n^2a_{n-1}$$

is independent of $n$, so $a_{n+1}^2a_n = a_2^2a_1$ for all $n$, and hence $\lambda^3 = a_2^2a_1$ for $\lambda = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$.

Comment: A friend and I had been breaking our heads over this one for quite a long while. This was fantastic!